# Express POST not working but GET and PATCH is

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, express, post

I'm trying to create some REST APIs for my project but I can't seem to get POST to work. I've tested GET and PATCH in Postman and they both work fine. Any help would be appreciated!

product.service.ts

```
export class ProductService {
  constructor(private readonly model: Model<ProductType>) {}

  public getProduct = async (id: string): Promise<ProductType | null> => {
    return await this.model.findOne({ id });
  };

  public createProduct = async ( 
    body: ProductType
  ): Promise<ProductType> => {
    return await this.model.create(body);
  };
}

export const productService = new ProductService(ProductModel);
```

product.controller.ts

```
export class productController {
  constructor(private readonly service: ProductService) {}

  public getProduct = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const response = await this.service.getProduct(req.params.id);
    res.send(response);
  };

  public createProduct = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const response = await this.service.createProduct(req.body);
    res.send(response);
  };
}

export const productController = new ProductController(
  productService
);
```

product.route.ts

```
const router: Router = express.Router();

router.get('/products/:id', productController.getProduct);
router.post('products/new', productController.createProduct); //this route returns a 404

export default router;
```

So when I try to post in Postman it returns a 404, but the get works fine. I appreciate any help!

Comment: The post route URL is missing the leading forward slash. `router.post('/products/new', productController.createProduct);`

Comment: Oh right! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks Will!

Comment: We all have those moments. Good luck on your coding journey! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the original post, I missed the forward slash in the post route URL.

Thanks!